# Use the shadowed property of the derived class in the base class

Tags: vb.net, oop, inheritance, shadow

I have two class, `CustomerService class` and `CellphoneCustomerService` class. `CellphoneCustomerServic` class derived from `CustomerService` class. The `CellphoneCustomerService` class shadows the `CustomerRepository` property of `CustomerService` class.

```
Public Class CustomerService
        <Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Dependency()> _
        Public Property CustomerRepository as ISQLRepository
            Set (Byval value As SQLRepository)
                _customerRepository = value
            End Set         
            Get 
                Return _customerRepository
            End Get
        End Property


        Public Sub Save(Byval Cust As Customer)
            Me.CustomerRepository.Save(object)
        End Sub

        Public Function GetAllCustomers(Byval Query As String) As Customer
            Me.CustomerRepository.GetAllCustomer(Byval Query As String)
        End Sub

        Public Function GetCustomer(Byval ID As Integer)
            Me.CustomerRepository.GetCustomer(object)
        End Sub             
End Class


Public Class CellphoneCustomerService
    Inherits CustomerService
        <Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Dependency()> _
        Public Shadow Property CustomerRepository As IOracleRepository
            Set (Byval value As OracleRepository)
                _customerRepository = value
            End Set         
            Get 
                Return _customerRepository
            End Get
        End Property            
End Class
```

My problem with this code is when I create an instance of `CellphoneCustomerService` class and use the Save method, `GetAllCustomers`, and `GetCustomer` function, it still uses the `CustomerRepository` property of the base class and not the shadowed `CustomerRepository` property of the derived class.

What I need to do is when the object is a `CellphoneCustomerService`, the base class should use the shadowed `CustomerRepository` property of the `CellphoneCustomerService` class but if the object is a `CustomerService` class it will use its own `CustomerRepository` property.

Comment: Why you used `C#` tag?

Comment: Without casting to the derived type, I'm not sure you can do that. You'll need to go down the proper virtual / override route. In C# at least, accessing a property that is hiding another requires a reference to the type directly, a reference to a base type would bypass the "hider" and go to the hidden property underneath.

Comment: You mean I have to create overriden function of GetAllCustomers, GetCustomer and Save method in the derived class?

Comment: You have make the Property Overridable in the base class, and override it in the derived class. I don't know the types you use, but it sounds like the Repositories have a common interface / parent. You have to use it as the type of the property.

Comment: @Waldfee, I tried your suggestion, I add Overridable to the property and Overrides it in the derived class. I got an error cannot overrides because they differ by thier return types. The two class has no common interfaces so I can't use it as their return types.

Comment: They have to share a common interface or else your solution won't work.  For instance, if they don't both have a `Save` method, it can't possibly work.  By explicitly specifying the interface, you will force the methods to be implemented properly.  However, if you can't do that for some reason, as long as `Option Strict` is `Off`, you can change the property type to `Object` and that should work.  It pains me to recommend that, though.

Comment: As shown in the edited code above, the reason I cannot use the common interface as thier return type because this property is used in dependency injection (Unity). As far as I know, in unity I cannot use one interface to initialize two objects?

Comment: That's precisely how dependency injection is supposed to work.  You shouldn't have to have two classes, you should just have one and you just give it the appropriate repository as a dependency.  I'm not familiar with Unity, but I imagine it must support that.  If not, it's a terrible DI framework and should not be used.

Comment: Can't you provide the specific type in the `Dependency` attribute for the property in the derived class, like: `<Dependency("OracleRepository")>`

Comment: Looks like I can do this, <Dependency("OracleRepository")> as discussed in this artcle http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649478.aspx.